# Classification of three-dimensional homogeneous spaces

Tags: differential-geometry

I would like to know whether it is possible to classify all three-dimensional Riemannian homogeneous spaces. I know that it is possible to classify all three-dimensional Lie algebras. Do you maybe know whether the same holds for all homogeneous spaces.